# Customizing the width of audio.js

Tags: javascript, css, audio

I have installed the audio.js plugin. I have entered this code to the header.php which is in the includes folder

```
<script src="audio/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
```

The other pages shows the player with the default size. But the site that i am creating, only in the homepage i need to change the width of the player.
Any idea?

Please help!!

Comment: How do you expect me to help you if I don't see the code? Post some code

Comment: <?php
       
       
            echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-6 hero-feature'>";
            echo "<div class='thumbnail'>";
            echo "<img src='musik/$row[Image]' alt='$row[Image]'>";
            echo "<div class='caption'>";
            echo "<h3>$row[Name]</h3>";
            echo "<p>$row[Description]</p>";
            echo "<audio src='musik/$row[FileName]' type='audio/mp3' width='75'/>";
            echo "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        
        ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the required css rules for the player you desire. Change the value of width of the div wrapping the audio tag.

```
echo "<div class='audiojs'>";
echo "<audio src='musik/$row[FileName]' preload='auto'></audio>";
echo "</div>";
```

css:

```
.audiojs{
   width:500px;
   height:50px;

}
```

Comment: Then what about the link that i have extracted from the header.php from the includes folder?

Comment: simply make this change in the css of the page you intend.

Comment: Still it doesn't work. i edited the code like                         echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-6 hero-feature'>";
            echo "<div class='thumbnail'>";
            echo "<img src='musik/$row[Image]' alt='$row[Image]'>";
            echo "<div class='caption'>";
            echo "<h3>$row[Name]</h3>";
            echo "<p>$row[Description]</p>";
            echo "<audio src='musik/$row[FileName]' preload='auto'></audio>";
            echo "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";

Comment: i did make the changes in the css. still doesn't work

Comment: The thickness of the player is increased. but it doesnt change the length of the player

Comment: great, you figured out.